# Correct way to implement react functional update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using below way to implement functional update.

```
let domainValidationSummary = getDomainValidationSummary;
domainValidationSummary.status = responseSummary.status;
setDomainValidationSummary(prev=> ({...prev,...domainValidationSummary}));
```

though its working, I feel there might be simpler/better way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever dealing with state in React, it almost always makes sense to let React handle updates for you. It looks like you could use the `useState` hook and leverage the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form to update your state based on the previous state:

```
// create domain with initial state
const [domainValidationSummary, setDomainValidationSummary] = React.useState({
  status: null,
  domainName: "",
  validated: false
});

// this is just an example object to provide an example
const responseSummary = {
  status: "complete",
  domainName: "example",
  validated: true,
};

setDomainValidationSummary((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  status: responseSummary.status,
  domainName: responseSummary.domainName,
  validated: responseSummary.validated,
}));
```

I'm not sure what or where `responseSummary` comes from or what the expected shape of `domainValidationSummary` should be, but if you're currently managing two objects and it makes sense to update your `domainValidationSummary` and `responseSummary` at the same time then `useReducer` would be another great option.

Comment: I'm using react state, your solution worked. how does it look if I have multiple properties to update  `setDomainValidationSummary((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  status: responseSummary.status, property1 : val
}));` ?

Comment: @ManishParab I've updated my answer to provide a more complete example of updating state. It's pretty similar to what was already there, but hopefully it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This can be just one line statement like below. Remove first two lines and use `responseSummary.status` in updating state.

```
// let domainValidationSummary = getDomainValidationSummary;
// domainValidationSummary.status = responseSummary.status;
setDomainValidationSummary(prev=> ({...prev, ...getDomainValidationSummary, status: responseSummary.status}));
```